# SQL Loop for date combinations

Tags: sql, loops

I am trying to create a temp table that uses a SQL while loop with variables that shows all possible incurred and paid dates of a service between the two variables.

The logic would work as follows:

- Start with start date, then paid date matches that start date.
- Next row, if paid date is less than max date then add one month, if it = max date then the incurred date = previous incurred date + 1 and paid date = paid date
- Continue until incurred date = paid date = max date

For example,

@startdate = '1/1/2016' and
@enddate = '3/1/2016',

So the table would show the following:

| Incurred Date | Paid Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2016 | 1/1/2016 |
| 1/1/2016 | 2/1/2016 |
| 1/1/2016 | 3/1/2016 |
| 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2016 |
| 2/1/2016 | 3/1/2016 |
| 3/1/2016 | 3/1/2016 |

The rule with these dates is paid dates must be on or after the incurred date. Something can not be paid before the service was incurred.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SQL doesn't have loops. SQL is all about set-based operations. How familiar are you with relational-algebra or relational-calculus?

Comment: Use a recursive cte,

Comment: @jarlh I don't see why a recursive CTE is necessary, or even a CTE at all: why not just `WHERE IncurredDate < PaidDate AND IncurredDate >= @startDate AND PaidDate < @endDate` ?

Comment: @Dai, the question isn't very clear, but I _think_ OP has a start and an end date, and wants a a result including dates between start and end.

Comment: @jarlh Right, but how does that suggest a CTE is necessary?

Comment: @Dai `SQL doesn't have loops` is inaccurate as there are `while` loops in sql

Comment: @Shmiel `WHILE` is not a part of SQL's query system (I've got my copy of the ISO SQL spec open right now). You're referring to optional _procedural_ features of SQL and vendor-specific extensions, both of which are invariably suboptimal compared to set-based queries - or at least always make me feel dirty whenever I use them.

Comment: @Dai, you can do it in another way if you want. I find a recursive cte very handy when _generating_ dates/calendars - that's why I suggested it.

Comment: Please show us some example source data, including full `CREATE TABLE` statements, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you need, I'm creating a recursive CTE to insert the range of dates in a table, then iterate between @startdate and @enddate and insert in a results table after each iteration.

```
declare @startdate date = '1/1/2016',
        @enddate date = '3/1/2016'

declare @dates table (Dat date)
declare @results table (IncurredDate date, PaidDate date)

--Recursive CTE to insert range of dates.
;with cte as
(
    Select Dat = @startdate
    Union All
    Select dateadd(month, 1, Dat) From cte
    where Dat < @enddate
)
Insert into @dates(Dat)
Select Dat
From cte

--Iterate over date range, insert in final table over each iteraction
While (@startdate <= @enddate)
Begin

    Insert into @results (IncurredDate, PaidDate)
    Select  @startdate,
            Dat
    From @dates
    where @startdate <= Dat 

    Set @startdate = dateadd(month, 1, @startdate)
End
```

[image: Results]